# Check if a field exists

Tags: custom-field, object

I have field with which I have to update  via `Workflow Rule`. But we don`t know in which object it is.

Is there any way I could check on which object(s) this field exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like. Just open your developer console and run this script

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> globalDescribe = Schema.getGlobalDescribe(); 
List<String> apiNames = new List<String>();

for(string objectApi: globalDescribe.keyset()){             
    apiNames.add(objectApi);
}

Schema.DescribeSobjectResult[] results  = Schema.describeSObjects(apiNames);
for(Schema.DescribeSobjectResult describeResult  : results){                

        for(Schema.SobjectField  field: describeResult.fields.getMap().values()){
            if(field.getDescribe().getName() == 'Field_API_Name')
                system.debug(field.getDescribe().getLabel()+'~~~~~~~~~~'+describeResult);  

        }
}
```

Comment: `console.log`?  you've got JS on the brain :-)

Comment: Thanks @cropredy I was fighting with javascript from long time.Everything is mixed now :)

Comment: thank you tushar, it give me the error, Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Schema.SObjectField].Describe()

Comment: @AnuragA its getDescribe() check my updated answer.

Answer (score 7):

You can use Force.com Eclipse IDE to get all standard and custom objects using the `RMB Project | Add Remove Metadata Components` then use the Search command on the field name to find the object

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There's an app on the appexchange that I've found really helpful for this. Metadata Search: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009wgF7EAI

It's a little more declarative way to search for metadata so you don't have to wait for eclipse to start up and then search through the org.